# Deque get a value by its position

Tags: java

How would I be able to return a list of queues and get the second one in line?
How would I return a value by its position with Deque?

Example:

```
Deque queue = new LinkedList();

public void QueneTesting(){
  queue.add("First in line");
  quene.add("Second in line");
  quene.add("Third in line");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Queue interface could not be used to traverse it's values or get a value by it's position, without removing elements from queue. Take a look at [JavaDoc for it's methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

But as long as it implements LinkedList in your case, you are able to cast your queue to List or even to LinkedList, if you need it's specific behaviour, and use it as you need it. For example, with simle List:

```
List list = (LinkedList) queue;
//print all content
for (String temp : list) {
  System.out.println(temp);
}
//get the second element in a list
String value = list.get(1);
```

Comment: Would i be able to get it it's value by position with a Deque?

Comment: Sure no, both queue and deque are not for such a usage. They are just to make fifo and lifo behaviour

Comment: In both cases you have to cast it to something else, to get any value by position

Comment: I'll just use LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
 then

Comment: Yes, it's a solution